# What is relationship between total_steps and num_steps of file pipeline.config?

Tags: tensorflow, pipeline, transfer-learning

I'm working on training a model by using Transfer Learning. The pre-trained model I use is "SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320" from [Model Zoo TF2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md). And I have some confusion about item `train_config`, in file `pipeline.config`.

If I change `num_steps`, model will train with `num_steps`. But when I change `total_steps`,  the model still train with `num_steps`. Even if I set`num_steps` > `total_step`, there is no error. And when I check all SSD model in Model Zoo TF2, I always see that `total_steps` the same as `num_steps`.

- **Question:** Do I need to set `total_steps` the same with `num_steps`? What is the relationship between it?

```
train_config {
  batch_size: 128
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.07999999821186066
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.026666000485420227
          warmup_steps: 1000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED"
  num_steps: 50000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "classification"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `num_steps` parameter in the training configuration specifies the number of steps to train the model for. On the other hand, the `total_steps` parameter is used in conjunction with learning rate schedules that decay the learning rate as training progresses.

In your case, the optimizer uses cosine decay learning rate schedule which decays the learning rate as training progresses based on the total number of steps specified by total_steps. If you don't specify this parameter, the learning rate will not decay.

If you set `num_steps` greater than `total_steps`, then the model will stop training once it completes num_steps. But if you set `total_steps` greater than `num_steps`, the learning rate will continue to decay beyond the point where training stops. In other words, `total_steps` is only used as a reference for the learning rate schedule and doesn't affect the actual number of training steps.

It's generally recommended to set `total_steps` greater than or equal to `num_steps` so that the learning rate continues to decay until the end of training.